# removing artifacts in a png

Tags: php, image, gd, artifacts

I've created my own algorithm to remove artifacts based on pixels. The only problem is that I have to manually specify the range of RGB based on a picture.

I'm trying to make it a bit more automatic, and have concluded that artifacts are usually very light colored and barely visible unless tilting the screen. Is there any RGB math that I can use to weed these artifacts out properly?

Comment: Can you post images of the original, and what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: sorry, the picture is copyrighted. the only thing i can tell you to help you better understand is that the artifacts are about (240,250,250) .. A VERY slight off-white color. I want to basically turn these artifacts white (255,255,255) which I have done properly. The problem is that I'm trying to find a common pattern that most artifacts have (that being -- a very very slight off white) I'm thinking of some universal RGB range that fits them mostly all of them (>240,>240,>240) or maybe some advanced RGB math that gets rid off all the very very slight coloring in the image

Comment: Then make an image that isn't copyrighted as an example.  There are many kinds of artifacts, and from your description, it isn't clear what is causing them.  Without knowing that, it is hard to suggest a way to remove them.  I don't know if your image is a photo, drawing, or just random pixels.  I don't know if you are trying to remove JPEG artifacts that have cropped up along the way, or stuck pixels on a camera's sensor.  You might be removing corrupt data.  Who knows... your question isn't clear enough, which is why you don't have any replies to it.

Comment: Have a look on Leadtools image processing library. They are not free but you might get the idea. Read about convolution filters. They are easy to implement if they are useful. Convert your images to BMP so that you can use them as a bit map. Try your convolution filters on 3-rd party image analysis software before to implement the algorithm. Be patient. There might be noise in your histogram. If artefacrs are uniformly diseminated, try Fourier filters.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way to do this is to use an adaptive blur on the image.  Very close to white will be turned white, and so on, but edges will stay intact.  Use ImageMagick, http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.adaptiveblurimage.php

Comment: interesting, this project is well in the past, but now i know something new. thanks.